# What does product_data_storage do?

Tags: magento2

I have noticed that images can take forever to load using the **fotorama image loader** on Magento 2 product pages after a user has used the website to view many products.

Clearing `product_data_storage` and `recently_viewed_products` from Local storage seems to dramatically speed this up and so feel these need cleaning every once in a while but I might just clear these out or stop them populating as am not really using recently viewed products.

What are these used for and are they required?